# Instantiating one CFC twice

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfc

When I try to instantiate one CFC from 2 different CFCs, ColdFusion returns a 500 error. I tried making one of the CFC extend the other, but it did not solve the issue. Is this possible, or am I simply doing something incorrectly?

```
<!--- one.cfc --->
<cfcomponent name="FirstCFC">
   <cfset this.Tools = createObject('component', 'toolbox').init()>
....
</cfcomponent>

<!--- two.cfc --->
<cfcomponent name="SecondFC">
   <cfset this.Tools = createObject('component', 'toolbox').init()>
....
</cfcomponent>

<!--- toolbox.cfc --->
<cfcomponent name="Toolbox">
   <cffunction name="init" access="public">
      <cfreturn this>
   </cffunction>

   <cffunction name="someFunc" access="public">
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is a screenshot of the 500 error

[image]

Here is a more "full" code sample

http://pastebin.com/zJ1zpHYy

Comment: A 500 error usually indicates a problem with your web server configuration. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Assuming that all three CFCs are in the same folder

Comment: The 500 error msg is probably also saying "switch on robust exception handling to see a better error" (or something to that sentiment).  Do that, so you get a proper error msg.  Or perhaps switch of "friendly error messages" if you're using IE.  It'll probably make it more obvious what your problem is.

Comment: I don't have access of the server, as this is work for a 3rd party. And the error goes away if I take out the duplicate instantiation.

Comment: Are the components in separate files? They should be so if they aren't then put in separate files named after the component name followed by ".cfc". Name is apparently not a valid attribute as the component name is actually taken from the cfc file name so try removing those as well. If still an issue then try commenting out all non-init code and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, the components are in separate files. I just tried taking commenting out all non-init code, and the problem is still there.

Comment: Change the two 'this.Tools' CFSETs to 'variables.Tools', ensure your cfclasses directory is empty, restart CF, and test again. The 'THIS' scope is implicitly a public scope (contrary to Java), and I have a feeling that based on how you're instantiating FirstCFC and SecondCFC, the two 'THIS' references are overwriting each other in their pseudo-constructors.

Comment: I also have a sneaking suspicion that there is some recursion going on as a part of methods not displayed in the OP...

Comment: @ShawnHolmes You are right. I didn't realize it until your comment. Toolbox.cfc instantiates SecondCFC and then I instantiate secondCFC from Toolbox.

Comment: I figured as much. I've added an answer for completeness, based on your response.

Comment: You did not say how the error occurs. You've shown the code for 3 CFCs, but nothing at all about how you used the CFCs. Can you please show the file (or portion there of) that makes use of one of these CFCs and creates the 500 error?

Comment: My first pass assumed the recursion happened based on creating A, private B, and B had a reference to A via THIS as opposed to VARIABLES. I've updated my answer, which is the more straight-forward A->B, which leads to B->A, and so on and so forth, making the THIS|VARIABLES theory moot (it would happen anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java stack trace you've included is indicitive of an **infinite recursion error**. Take care when creating objects of type A, which have a new object of type B in their pseudo-constructor. If the object B *itself* creates an object of type A in *its* pseudo-constructor, you have yourself an infinite recursion of objects being created, ending in an ugly java stack trace.

Comment: Yeah - I can see that causing the error - but nothing in his code shows that though. I wish he would post more code.

Comment: yes.. his sample didn't show an additional instantiation that would cause this - but his comments seem to indicate that it was indeed the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn is right. He posted more code and you can see two.cfc makes tools.cfc and tools.cfc makes two.cfc.

You need to move to an injection style setup (ala ColdSpring for example).